# Unexpected forall syntax error

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, opl

So i wanted to run this code:

```
constraint ctMachine[Machine];
subject to{
forall(i in Machine)
  forall (k in Week)
  ctMachine[i]: sum(j in Product)
    ResourceConsumption[i][j] * Units[j][k]  <= Capacity[i];
```

But if I do this, I get the error that ctMachine[1] was already assigned, which makes sense. So I tried to put the second for loop after the sum function, like this:

```
constraint ctMachine[Machine];
subject to{


forall(i in Machine)
  ctMachine[i]: sum(j in Product)
  forall(k in Week)
    ResourceConsumption[i][j] * Units[j][k]  <= Capacity[i];
```

But then I receive the syntax error, unexpected forall. But how can I do it then. I need the constranint for all k. I am fairly new to linear programming and OPL so I don't have a clue how I can solve this now. Btw I can't just remove the constraint label since I also need that.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove

> constraint ctMachine[Machine];

and write

> forall(i in Machine)
>     ctMachine: 
>     sum(j in Product)
>     sum(k in Week)
>       ResourceConsumption[i][j] * Units[j][k]  <= Capacity[i];

regards